# Sintaxe de FOR em C

Tags: c, for, sintaxe

Sou novo na comunidade, e recentemente observei em um código de C, um laço de repetição FOR, com a seguinte sintaxe. for(;;).
Alguém saberia me explicar essa sintaxe.
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando for(;;) é um loop infinito. Para sair desse loop usa-se normalmente o comando break. Assim

```
for (;;)
{
  ...
  ...
  if (alguma_condicao)
    break; // sai do loop
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Legal, obrigado por responder. Muito legal, essa sintaxe do for, e bem útil também. Valeu.

Comment: Então marque a solução como resposta.

Comment: Desculpe-me mas tal utilização do comando for desta maneira não é nada legal. Se deve permanecer no loop até constatar alguma condição então utilize o while ou do/while.

Comment: @anonimo, loops infinitos são um pattern comum em C e C++...alguma pessoas preferem "while (true)", outras preferem "for (;;)" .., veja [aqui](https://www.dipmat.univpm.it/~demeio/public/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf) na página 60 do livro K&R eles falando do loop "for (;;)"